# Use of related field name in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-key-relationship

I have tow models like below:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    q = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class B(models.Model):
    c = models.Foreignkey('A', related_name='bb')
    d = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    e = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my view:

```
class Myview(ListView):

    model = A
    template_name = 'admin/layer.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['mylist'] = A.objects.filter(bb__e=False)
        return context
```

Everything is working fine except In my template 'admin/layer.html' I am trying this:

```
{% for list in mylist %}
    {{ list.bb.d }}
{% endfor %}
```

but I do not get any value for `{{ list.bb.d }}` Can I use related field name in this way in django template ?

Answer (score 10):

Note that `list.bb` will only give you the [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager). Here an instance of `A` can be related to multiple instances of `B`.

So to get them all you need to use following syntax:

```
{% for a_obj in mylist %}
    {% for b_obj in a_obj.bb.all %}
        {{ b_obj }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

More details provided [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

> You can override the `FOO_set` name by setting the `related_name` parameter in the `ForeignKey` definition. For example, if the `Entry` model was altered to `blog = ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entries')`, the above example code would look like this:
>
> ```
> >>> b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)  
> >>> b.entries.all() # Returns all Entry objects related to Blog.
> ```

Comment: Alternatively you should should switch to using a `OneToOneField` if only one `B` object should be linked to `A`.

Comment: I am thinking so @solarissmoke

Comment: Thanks @AKS. May be I got it.

Comment: @cjahangir Glad to be of help.

Comment: Hi all, I have edited my post. I have added extra field to model **B** and also have changed my context queryset. What is the case now?

Comment: Nothing would change because you are still using the `ForiegnKey`.