# how to access foreign key in a model class into django templates

Tags: django

I want to access all foreign key fields of my **Answer** class in the template.

**models.py**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)   
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    answer = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=1)
```

**views.py**

```
def questions(request):
context = { "questions": Question.objects.all(),
            "answers": Answer.objects.all(),
            "departments": Department.objects.all(),
            "semesters": Semester.objects.all(),
            "teachers": Teacher.objects.all(),
            "subjects": Subject.objects.all(),
            "rating_choices": RATING_CHOICES,
            }
return render(request, "evaluation/questions.html", context)
```

in the template, I want to access teacher, question, and subject through **Answer** class to build a form for submission. like this:
[image]

This is my template that I think is problematic.

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 5%;">
<br>
<form action="{% url 'evaluation:index' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <select name="semester" id="semester_id">
      {% for semester in semesters %}
        <option value="{{ semester }}">{{ semester }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  
    <select name="teacher" id="teacher_names">
      {% for teacher in answers %}
        <option value="">{{ teacher.get_teacher_name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  
    <select name="department" id="department_name">
      {% for department in departments %}
        <option value="{{ department }}">{{ department }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    
    <select name="subject" id="subject_name">
      {% for subject in subjects %}
        <option value="{{ subject }}">{{ subject }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  <ol>
      <br>
    {% for question in questions %}
    <li>
      {{ question }}
        {% for choice in rating_choices %}
        <ul>
          <input type="radio" name="question_{{question.id}}" value="{{ choice.0 }}"> {{ choice.1 }}
        </ul> 
        {% endfor %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %} 
  </ol>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>    
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to add a related_name to the foreign key
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

with the related name you can reference this model:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="forums")
    forum_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Python Example : `Category.objects.all().forums.get(pk=1)`

Template Example :

```
{% for cat in category %}
  {% for forum in cat.forums.all %}
    {{ forum.forum_name }}
  {% endfor %}  
{% endfor %}
```

[Use of related field name in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018886/use-of-related-field-name-in-django-template)